# Accidentally formated /dev/sda1 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grubrescue, boot-repair

When trying to format an USB drive, I accidentally formatted the `/dev/sda1` file system, which appears to contain information needed to start ubuntu. I realized that so I decided to not shut down the computer, and trying to repair instead.

I tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, it gives me:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I tried using bootrepair and this gives:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
```

This is my state now:

[image]

Is there something I can do to repair my file?

My computer is still on.

EDIT: The output of boot repair is here:
[boot-repair output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23063440/)

EDIT: RESPONSE to wjandrea, I tried changing the flag, that is why it says bios_grub flag, but I don't know how to make it "unformatted", which option is of the ones offered by gparted when formatting?

EDIT: RESPONSE to oldfred. Yes the original flag was boot. Based on this thread [Problems with booting ubuntu after formatting boot partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421757/problems-with-booting-ubuntu-after-formatting-boot-partition), I searched for `/sys/firmware/efi` and it exits, as indicative of an EFI boot.
My knowledge of ubuntu is nothing but having it installed on my pc once to avoid using windows. The output of `cat /etc/fstab` is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=bb009bf9-af36-471a-825d-505f28b194ee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E957-26C4  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=26cf563f-438e-41cb-a11b-30b4bb99a433 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: You have the instructions already: "create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag)". That's referring to `/dev/sda1`. It already has the flag, so you just need to create the partition then run Boot Repair again.

Comment: Post this: `cat /etc/fstab` With the size of sda1, it looks more like an ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 formatted with boot flag for UEFI boot. A normal bios_grub partition for BIOS boot is only 1 or 2MB. And Boot-Repair is trying to reinstall a BIOS boot verison of grub which then requires the bios_grub partition.

Comment: I edited to question to include more information.

Comment: @FranciscoAngel oldfred is right, it should actually be a UEFI partition. So create a FAT32 partition and change the flag to `boot` instead of `bios_grub`.

Comment: wjandrea, I returned dev/sda1 to fat32 and boot flag,  what do I do now? boot-repair still gives the `GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.` . How can I instruct boot repair to treat the system as UEFI instead of BIOS?

Comment: @FranciscoAngel I think you now need to reinstall grub, but I'm not 100% sure. BTW, you need to put an @ before my name to send me a notification.

Comment: @wjandrea , how can I install grub? both `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `boot-repair` gave me the same messages as indicated in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally

```
sudo grub-install dev/sda
```

worked after I run:

```
sudo mount dev/sda1 /boot/efi
```

based on the information contained here [how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the section "Creating an EFI System Partition" here [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition). 
Now I get the error

```
The disk drive for /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting o M for manual recovery.
```

After skipping, the computer started succesfully. Being able to shut down and restart the computer is enough for me now. I will take my time to solve this new problem, most probably in a new thread.
Best regards.